# The "end" statement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have a `if`, `else`, and `else if` statement, and I'm using the official documentation for Ruby, but I can't figure out where to put my `end` statements.

Here is the code:

```
class Menu
  def principal_menu
    user_input = gets
    #On supprime le \n du retour à la ligne
    user_input = user_input.chomp
    if user_input == "3"
      exit
    else if user_input == "1"
      if File.exists?("accounts.txt")
    else 
      File::new("accounts.txt","w+")
    end

    else if user_input == "2"
      new_account = account.new
    end
  end
end
```

The error is: `AccountManager.rb:63: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Note: Line 63 is the very end of the file.

Could some one help a newbie in Ruby :D

Thanks!

Comment: In ruby, `else if` is `elsif`.

Comment: Here's a ProTip: indent the code properly. Even better, use an editor with automated reformatting. Many many syntax errors become very obvious when your code is properly formatted.

Comment: _Not_ if you want nothing to happen by default. @CarySwoveland

Comment: @Sergio, I know. My remark was intended to be a general one, but was not well-stated, so I've deleted it.

Comment: I know about indentation, the thing is that I've been using this file for many tests and at the end, it was like a mess, I know I should not do that, but.. hey, you know... Thanks anyway! (Using notepad++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
class Menu
    def principal_menu
        user_input = gets
        #On supprime le \n du retour à la ligne
        user_input = user_input.chomp
        if user_input == "3"
            exit
        else if user_input == "1"
            if File.exists?("accounts.txt")
                # you aren't doing anything here
            else 
                File::new("accounts.txt","w+")
            end
        else if user_input == "2"
            new_account = account.new
        end
    end
end
```

In Ruby, you use `elsif` instead of `else if`. This can stump new-to-Ruby people.

This is correct:

```
class Menu
    def principal_menu
        user_input = gets
        #On supprime le \n du retour à la ligne
        user_input = user_input.chomp
        if user_input == "3"
            exit
        elsif user_input == "1"
            if File.exists?("accounts.txt")

            else 
                File::new("accounts.txt","w+")
            end

        else user_input == "2"
            new_account = account.new
        end
    end
end
```